# Pandas groupby to return sum and latest date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to this one:

```
data = {
    "index": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    "batchId": [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200],
    "amount": [50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450],
    "date": [
        "2020-11-24 15:00:00",
        "2020-11-24 15:00:00",
        "2020-11-25 15:00:00",
        "2020-11-25 15:00:00",
        "2020-11-25 15:00:00",
        "2020-11-25 15:00:00",
        "2020-11-25 15:00:00",
        "2020-11-25 15:00:00",
        "2020-11-26 15:00:00",
    ],
}
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data)  

   index  batchId  amount                 date
0      0      100      50  2020-11-24 15:00:00
1      1      100     100  2020-11-24 15:00:00
2      2      100     150  2020-11-25 15:00:00
3      3      100     200  2020-11-25 15:00:00
4      4      100     250  2020-11-25 15:00:00
5      5      200     300  2020-11-25 15:00:00
6      6      200     350  2020-11-25 15:00:00
7      7      200     400  2020-11-25 15:00:00
8      8      200     450  2020-11-26 15:00:00
```

I'm trying to group by the `batchId` column, then sum by the `amount` column and also add the latest date of the summed batch.

So far I have only managed to sum up the amounts based on the `batchId`:

```
batch_amounts = (
    data_frame["amount"].groupby(data_frame["batchId"]).sum().reset_index()
)
```

Which gives:

```
   batchId  amount
0      100     750
1      200    1500
```

How can I also add the date column that will show the latest date of each batch?

```
   batchId  amount                 date
0      100     750  2020-11-25 15:00:00
1      200    1500  2020-11-26 15:00:00
```

Comment: Use `data_frame.groupby(['batchId']).agg({'amount' : 'sum', 'date': 'max'}, as_index=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
data_frame["date"] = pd.to_datetime(data_frame["date"])
result = data_frame.groupby(["batchId"], as_index=False).agg(
    {"amount": "sum", "date": "max"}
)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   batchId  amount                 date
0      100     750  2020-11-25 15:00:00
1      200    1500  2020-11-26 15:00:00
```

Comment: Added `as_index` to avoid `.reset_index`, and formatted code using `black`, feel free to revert if not okay.

Comment: @Ch3steR Is ok with me :)